# How to display a variable into a text input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

in the `QandATable.php` I have a form below which contains a file input and an iframe:

```
var $fileVideo = $("<form action='videoupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_video' onsubmit='return videoClickHandler(this);' class='videouploadform' >" + 
"Video File: <input name='fileVideo' type='file' class='fileVideo' /></label>" +  
"<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
 "<p class='listVideo' align='left'></p>" +
"<iframe class='upload_target_video' name='upload_target_video' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Now below I have a jquery code which is triggered when the file has finished uploading.

```
  function stopVideoUpload(success, videofilename){

      var result = '';
      videocounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
          $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename));
      }


      return true;   
}
```

Now the result of the file upload and the file name is determined with the code below. But what my question is that how can I display the `$id` variable in a text input?

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>,'<?php echo $id . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] ?>');
 </script>
```

Comment: You can't just mix javascript and php, if that is what you are asking. For communication between javascript(client-side) and php(server-side) you have to use AJAX - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp. Also, note that the AJAX request can be simplified with javascript libraries like jQuery

Comment: @intelis I have been trying to follow the W3school example but can't seem to get it working. Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but if you change `type='text'` to `type='hidden'` on your input field, then the $id variable will be in a hidden input.

Comment: Sorry, I rushed my question, I meant turn it into a text input, not a hidden input, sorry bout that